# How should I go about making requests to MySQL from an Intel XDK web app?

Tags: mysql, html, web-applications, intel-xdk

I am working on a thin web application which takes in some search criteria, searches a mysql database and then returns that information on another page in the app. I am new to Intel XDK and to web applications in general. What I would really appreciate is some instructions and pseudocode or even links to places that would help. I'm just not sure about which code goes where with the XDK. Any help would be great. Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><!--HTML5 doctype-->

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="intelxdk.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
var isIntel=window.intel&&window.intel.xdk
// This event handler is fired once the intel libraries are ready
function onDeviceReady() {
    //hide splash screen now that our app is ready to run
    intel.xdk.device.hideSplashScreen();
    setTimeout(function () {
        $.ui.launch();
    }, 50);
}
//initial event handler to detect when intel is ready to roll
document.addEventListener("intel.xdk.device.ready", onDeviceReady, false);
</script>
<script src="js/appframework.ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
if(isIntel)
    $.ui.autoLaunch = false;
$.ui.useOSThemes = true; //Change this to false to force a device theme
$.ui.blockPageScroll();
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($.ui.useOSThemes && (!$.os.ios||$.os.ios7))
        $("#afui").removeClass("ios");
});
</script>
<link href="css/icons.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="css/af.ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="afui" class="ios">
    <div id="header" class="header"></div>
    <div id="content" style="">
        <div class="panel" title="Main" data-nav="nav_0" id="main" selected="selected"
        style="" data-appbuilder-object="page">

        <div class="container" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: relative;" data-appbuilder-object="container">
            <img src="images/PLD_banner_1100.jpg" style="width: 100%; height: auto;" alt="Title"
            data-appbuilder-object="image" class="" title="PLDbanner">
            <div class="select_element form_element" style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden; margin-bottom: 15px;"
            data-appbuilder-object="select">
                <label for="">Search Category:</label>
                <select id="" multiple="multiple">
                    <option value="filenum" selected="">File Number</option>
                    <option value="listeeName">Listee Name</option>
                    <option value="standard">Standard</option>
                    <option value="productdesc">Product Description</option>
                    <option value="lmac">Listed Model/Additional Company</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="select_element form_element" style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden;"
            data-appbuilder-object="select">
                <label for="">Search for...</label>
                <select id="" multiple="multiple">
                    <option value="exact" selected="">Exact Text</option>
                    <option value="all">All Keywords</option>
                    <option value="any">Any Keywords</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="text_item" data-appbuilder-object="text" style="margin-top: 15px; margin-bottom: 15px; text-align: center;">Enter File Number, Listee Name, Product Description, Standard or
                Listed Model.</div>
            <div class="input_element form_element" style="width: 100%; overflow: auto; margin-bottom: 15px;"
            data-appbuilder-object="input">
                <label for="txtSearch"></label>
                <input type="text" style="float:left;" id="txtSearch" placeholder="">
            </div><a class="button" href="#" style="position: relative; width: 100%; z-index: 2;"
            data-appbuilder-object="button" data-transition="slide">Search</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel" title="New Page" data-nav="nav_0" id="page_1" data-appbuilder-object="page"
    style=""></div>
    <div class="panel" title="New Page" data-nav="nav_0" id="page_2" data-appbuilder-object="page"
    style=""></div>
    <div class="panel" title="New Page" data-nav="nav_0" id="page_3" data-appbuilder-object="page"
    style=""></div>
</div>
<div id="navbar" class="footer">
    <a href="#main" class="icon home">Home</a>
</div>
<header id="header_0" data-appbuilder-object="header">
    <a id="backButton" href="#" class="button backButton" style="visibility: visible; ">Back</a>
    <h1 id="pageTitle" class="">test</h1> 
</header>
<nav id="nav_0" data-appbuilder-object="nav">
    <h1>Side Menu</h1>
</nav>
</div>
</body>




</html>
```

This is the code I have for the main page of my web app. Most of it is built in (I chose appStarter) and then the forms I mainly just dragged and dropped onto the interface versus actually hard coding it myself. So I'm a major newbie here.

Comment: you need to have some server, than build some api on this server and send your requests from your app to the server and get the results back. search google for api

Comment: THanks for the reply. I understand that I will write some AJAX/Jquery which will send the user input to another page connected to a server I have access to and then return the requested results on another XDK page. I guess what I'm asking is where does the Jquery go? And is it alright for the xdk to communicate with a middle-man web page which will control the server query? In this case it's an ASP.NET page.

Answer (score 0):

I handle my AJAX requests on a javascript file. I think XDK brings a default file called index_user_scripts.js under the js folder of your directory (www), you can add your functions there or create your own .js file. You must include it at the bottom of the head of your index.html like this:

```
       <head>
          /*stylesheets and other stuff goes here*/
       <script type="application/javascript" src="js/index_user_scripts.js"></script> 
       </head>
```

An example of a function using AJAX:

```
        `$(function() 
        {
          $("#searchButton").click(function() 
          {
            $.ajax
           ({
              type: "POST",
              url: "http://yourwebpage.php",
              data: string,
              success: function(xml) 
              {

               },
              error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
              {
                alert(errorThrown.message);
               }

           });

        });

       });`
```

Hope this helps you!